# Assigning button to variable works on creation, error on selecting existing element?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript2.0

```
let button:Element = document.createElement("button");//Works
let button:HTMLButtonElement = document.createElement("button");//Works

let button2:Element = document.getElementsByTagName("button");//Error why?
let button3:HTMLButtonElement = document.getElementsByTagName("button");//Error why??????
```

With the help of vs code I understand the interfaces missing classlist and autofocus property correspondingly. But if so

- Why its acceptable when creating the element?
- How to assign a variable to a existing element and add event listener to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not acceptable because both

```
let button2:Element = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
let button3:HTMLButtonElement = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
```

return an array and not a single element. To fix this e.g. pick the first item from the array:

```
let button2:Element = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
let button3:HTMLButtonElement = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
```

Comment: Thanks you! thanks a lot. I get confused in many different ways for this simple thing.